# Through transit of check-in baggages

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, american-airlines

On my return trip from US to India I will be flying from Oklahoma to Kolkata transiting through Chicago & Abu Dhabi : OKC to ORD domestic flight AA, ORD to AUH &  AUH to CCU by Etihad.

Will my baggages be checked through all the way to CCU while I will be checking in at OKC? This trip was booked on one single ticket from Etihad.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to verify when you check-in at the counter.

According to this question in the [Etihad airlines Baggage Allowance policy](https://www.etihad.com/en-us/fly-etihad/baggage) question section, for the US:

> ### I have a connecting flight. Will my checked-in bags go to my final destination?
>
> Not always. You may need to pick up your bag and check it in again,
>   depending on the route and country you are travelling through. Your
>   agent can confirm when you check in at the airport.

Generally, your bags should make it to the destination you've paid for, but double check that Abu Dhabi airport security will not require a re-check of your bags. It should be fine since you are booked all the way through on one ticket, but some airports have different rules and regulations. Etihad suggests you ask during check-in.

Comment: With both segments on Etihad and a single booking, Etihad will transfer the bags.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you would think but their website states differently.

Comment: @AussieJoe there are a few exceptions to the automatic transfer, including transit in the US when arriving from abroad, but I don’t think the quoted itinerary has any reason not to allow it.

Comment: @AussieJoe Where do you see that their website states differently?

Comment: @MichaelHampton look at the link I provided to Etihad baggage policy. Read it, it is pretty clear in that it states to check in with the counter and ask them about bag transfers. Seems straightforward.

Comment: That advice is much too generic and doesn't really do much to address the (quite complex) issue of airline baggage handling. For people who may need visas for transit countries, it is virtually useless.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's literally the official advice from the ticket issuer. It doesn't get any more clear than that, sorry. It's also the easiest, and provides no room for guesswork.

Comment: Yes, it's "official" advice. It's also very poor advice. We can and must do better.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's not poor advice. It's pretty straightforward in telling you that not all routes are the same. I would call them now to confirm the answer. I really don't care what AA says, I have flown with them enough to know they're not always right. Especially when you're not on American soil.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have a single ticket on your PNR (booking) then American will check your bags through all the way to your destination.

Note that while AA is a oneworld airline, Etihad is not. It's also possible (but quite uncommon) to have two separate tickets on a single PNR. If your booking is comprised of two tickets, one for the AA segment and another one for the EY segments, then [American will only check your bags to Chicago](https://saleslink.aa.com/en-US/documents/Archives/AgencyRef/Baggage-Through_Checked_Baggage_Policy-Separate_Tickets.pdf), and you will have to transfer your bags yourself at O'Hare.

> For customers holding a single ticket that involves other airline flights down-line from American, American will continue to through-check their bags to the next point of stopover.
>
> For customers holding a separate ticket for down-line connecting flights booked in the same PNR, American will continue to through-check bags exclusively to oneworld airlines to the point of stopover and collect the other airlines’ applicable baggage charges.

Check your confirmation email from Etihad to see if you have two different ticket numbers for the AA and EY segments, or the same ticket number.

In both cases, Etihad will transfer your bags at Abu Dhabi, as you have a single booking and Etihad operates both segments in and out of AUH.

Comment: All the flights (AA domestic & 2 EY international) are under same ticket number.